# Azure MS SQL firewall settings (Azure MS SQL and WinForms clients on dynamic IP public network) WHAT is the best secure approach?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-security

I'm finishing a desktop App (Winforms). Azure MS SQL on server-side and WinForms clients. So they can come from unpredictable IP... So its impossible set new firewall Azure rule for every client network move...
My question what is the best approach to secure access from clients and how to set Azure firewall rules...
(the client uses a SQL server login)

on some forums, people recommend bypassing the azure firewall by setting rule 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 but it does not seem as good secure solution for me)

possible solutions I'm considering:
a) Setup a VPN on AZURE for the client (any tip for a good tutorial, and how to limit client traffic only for AZURE = client watching youtube will not spend my azure budget?

b) any third party VPN? (most of the VPN providers don't offer permanent IP but dynamic range)

c) another way

Thanks!
Pavel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a Client, Server, Database architecture. As a rule you generally don't want your clients connecting directly to a database. If you configure a WebAPI to contact the DB and allow your clients to communicate with that API it would be a much better approach

Comment: I know about this way but I d like to minimize the programming work... app is almost ready :(  I prefer "network setting" solution...

Comment: It really depends on your use case, if you're willing to require all users to connect to your custom VPN before they can use your application you can do that. You could try writing a simple proxy API for the DB, it wouldn't take too much effort and has multiple pros. The alternative, as stated by Microsoft in a document [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/accessing-sql-azure-from-winforms/) is that you must whitelist the IP's of users accessing the system, and if you can't guarantee the IP address of the users you'll need to allow all IP's which as you stated is a security risk.

Comment: Finally a best solution was choosen a custom VPN server with public IP. Connection is secured by the firewall rules and VPN connection. Far enough as i hope...